# Basis representation for non-negative, compact support, reasonably smooth spectral function

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, physics, mathematical-physics, applications

I was wondering if anyone has ideas on representing a **non-negative, compact support** (from x=-1 to 1 on the real axis) spectral function as a **superposition of basis elements**. Ideally, the basis representation should be **reasonably smooth** (physically, the spectral function represents the density of states).

I have tried using the Gaussian function with varying widths, but it seems to lack the continuity to represent a physical quantity (too many oscillations). Orthogonal polynomials (eg.Legendre) could work, but those basis functions are not non-negative, so I was wondering if anyone has ideas on representing this spectral function with an ideal, or at least reasonable, basis other than the Gaussian basis.

Thank you all.

Comment: [B-splines.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline)